# How to handle string response in swift 3 using alamofire

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I am trying to hit the url whose response is:

> "dbdg96t7331e150600836bc5dc026cc1649a887fc8b921b6111172db399d03566a944946e3cd13246901128413c3c9673d4e806a4v7j2yxe".

So how can I handle this string from response? Here is my code:

```
    temp = "Resident|" + user_uid
    let url = "http://api.appname.my/encodedecode.php?text=\(temp)"
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
        print(responseObject)
    }
```

In response I am getting this:

> FAILURE: invalidURL("http://api.appname.my/encodedecode.php?text=Resident|uP6zkPihw1MPleJQ44WV1rsH1dO2")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe (`|`) needs to be escaped in an URL

```
temp = ("Resident|" + user_uid).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
```

and `Alamofire.request` might expect a real `URL` object

```
let url = URL(string: "http://api.appname.my/encodedecode.php?text=\(temp)")!
```